# react-Countdown Timer (minor out of sync) problem after refreshing the screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, countdown

I have an auction site in MERN stack with socket.io  and i seem to have this unsolvable problem which i think is related to browsers and basic JS

**Flow**:

- whenever a product is added by admin, socket broadcasts it with all
  of details (including time )to all clients.
- the clients can bid on them and stuff.
- if a user refreshes the screen , it requests the    socket for latest
  product time and starts countdown from that time.

Everything is fine except some times react-countdown is lagging 0.5 second to 1 second behind whenever page is refreshed (**please note that problem does not occur when opening same auction on new tab**)

**Note: i have also tried self made Countdown timer using setInterval but the problem does not go away**

I am seeking assistance with this problem and am willing to compensate someone for their time and efforts to work with me directly to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `setInterval` and `setTimeout` means you are at the mercy of the browser. Browsers will often slow down the execution of these if some other process is happening and return to it once that's done, or if you switch away to another tab, they will purposefully reduce the tick rate. The level of accuracy you require is not easily achieved.

Firstly, I would suggest that getting the time it ends, then finding the difference between then and now, and counting down from this value with 1s increments will aggravate this problem. If each "tick" is off by even a small amount, this will accumulate into a larger error. This is probably what the library is doing by default. It may have also been what you were doing when you made your own timer, but I'd need to see it to confirm.

Instead, you need to store the time it ends passed from the socket (or keep it in scope like below) and on each "tick", work out the difference between then and now, every single time.

You could do this by using `react-countdown` in controlled mode and doing this logic in the parent.

I've made up a function here which would be the thing that receives the time from the socket -- or it's called from it. It's pseudo-code:

```
const timer = useRef(null) 
const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(null) // In seconds

const handleSocketReceived = (({endTime}) => {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
        const newTimeLeft = endTime - Date.now() // Pseudo code, depends on what end time is, but basically, work out the diff
        setTimeLeft(newTimeLeft)
    }, 100) // Smaller period means more regular correction

}, [])

// ...

useEffect(() => {
   return () => clearInterval(timer.current)
}, [])

// ...

 <Countdown date={timeLeft} controlled={true} />
```